# In Elm, when value under a signal has a compound type such as a list, how to efficiently update one element

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, frp, elm

I'm rather new to Elm, and I'm deeply attracted by the way Elm dealing with GUI. But after some deep thought, I find it's hard to efficiently update just one element of a list or finger tree (Just like finger tree in Haskell, if it already exists in Elm's library) which is under a Signal and the size of it also varies against time.

Specifically, to express a dynamic finger tree, we have to write

> Signal [ {-the finger tree's element type-} ]

But if we want to update just one element of the finger tree efficiently, we have to write

> Signal [ Signal {-the core data type-} ]

But in Elm the Signal is not a Monad, then how to flatten the two layer Signals into one layer?

Comment 1: I don't know in detail how Elm behaves in this situation. Reprocessing the whole finger tree is just my guess.

Comment 2: For example, suppose we have a signal value, marked as `s`, of type `Signal (fingerTree Int)`, and the following function, marked as `f`, whose input is `s` is, for example, `lift (fmap (+1))` whose type is `Signal (fingerTree Int) -> Signal (fingerTree Int)`. And if `s` has just one element changed, function `f` has to re-do the (+1) operation for every element of `s`. Obviously, it's a waste of time and I'm not sure if Elm is intelligent enough to detect the immutability.

Comment: As far as I know you can not flatten the Signal. But probably you can just update everything, and only the changed things will be redrawn due to ["diffing"](http://elm-lang.org/blog/Blazing-Fast-Html.elm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's really not what I need. I want a build in feature.

Comment: To make sure I understand your question correctly: Would [this](http://share-elm.com/sprout/544c0d3de4b00800031fe2b3) be a valid minimal example describing your problem? And you are worried about the performance because every `fib` is calculated over and over with every click?

Comment: Yes, that's just what I said to some extent. And I my question is: even if fib is very fast, when the list gets very large how can we just change the 4th element without update the whole list.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: Implement your logic/data processing as pure functions and lift them to transform signals.

The trick is to write a function `processList : [elementType] -> [elementType]` that provides the logic you want (check if the third element is a wibbler and change it to a wobbler or whatever you wanted to do), and then use the lift function which has type

```
lift : (a -> b) -> Signal a -> Signal b
```

like `lift processList mySignalThatProducesLists` to edit the data produced by `mySignalThatProducesLists` using `processList`.

The main idea here is that you encode the logic and data processing as pure functions and then use them as Signal transformers using `lift`. It's like Elm automatically reapplies the function every time the data in the source signal is updated.

If you're used to programming in Haskell, you can think of `Signal a` as a newtype wrapper around `Time -> a` for some opaque Time type, and `lift` as `fmap`. You don't need to have a monad to edit data.

There are also `lift2` and`lift3`functions for lifting functions with more than one argument, so again to use a Haskell analogy, you essentially have the capabilities of an Applicative functor there.

The reason they don't have a Monad is that that imposes implementation details that reduce efficiency. It may be that there's some equivalent of ArrowApply in there that I haven't spotted (that would give you an expressibility eqiuivelent of Monad), but I'm not sure there is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I really mean is update just one element of a list. Wrap an entire List into a Signal is not efficient, as the computer has to process the entire list all over again(I don't know in detail how Elm behaves in this situation. Reprocessing the whole list is just my guess).

Comment: @TorosFanny Can you be a bit more specific about what you want to achieve? Of course you can edit a particular element of a list with a pure function. Which element do you want to edit, under what circumstances, and in what way? Where is the list coming from? The earlier in the list you edit, the more quickly it works, since the remainder will be unedited.

Comment: For example, if the only way to express a dynamic sized list is to wrap the list under a Signal, to my knowledge, then we have to write something like Signal [Int] for a dynamic sized list. Then when the list's size becomes very big, updating the list is always a big work even if the new list just has only one element changed.

Comment: @TorosFanny That really depends how far along the list the element is. It's very fast at the beginning of the list and slower at the end. This matches the efficiency impact of using a linked list in other languages. If you regularly want to edit values a long way from the start, then a list is the wrong data structure. Lists are good for seqentially processing all elements.

Comment: @TorosFanny What was it you wanted to store and process in your large list?

Comment: Ok, it's true that accessing the last few elements of a long list is slow. But in theory there are some data types such as finger tree both dynamic sized and can accessed any elements quickly. So, here, I replace the above "list" with "finger tree", and ask the above question again.

Comment: Well with faster access and less deep structure you naturally get faster update. Only the structure on the way to the element you're changing gets touched, the rest is left as is.